# Can we use a cine lens for still photography also.

Tags: samyang

Some lenses from Samyang or Rokinon are coming with for cinema marking. Cant we use them for still photography also ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's in the right mount for your camera (or adaptable), you certainly *can*. However, be aware that:

- Cine lenses are going to be manual focus only. Maybe not a problem, maybe a deal breaker. (Probably not a problem if you're talking about a Samyang / Rokinon / all the other indentical brands as they're manual focus anyway).
- Cine lenses are either [ridiculously expensive](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20081/why-are-cine-lenses-so-much-more-expensive) or [not really cine lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/65076) - just the same glass with follow focus gearing etc. They'll still have lots of focus breathing and all the other things that a true cine lens can't have.

Given that at least the Samyang [cine lenses](http://www.samyang-lens.co.uk/samyang-21mm-t15-cine-lens.html) seem to be more expensive than the equivalent [photo lens](http://www.samyang-lens.co.uk/samyang-21mm-f14-ed-umc-lens.html), I'd say you're better off just getting the photo lens if you're not going to be using the cine "features".